# How handle long press event in react web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, material-ui, long-press

everyone! I use react and material ui library. I want to handle click event and long-press event separately. I think problem related to async set state, but for now, I don't know how to handle  this events

```
const [isCommandHandled, setIsCommandHandled] = React.useState(null);
const handleButtonPress = function (e) {
    setIsCommandHandled(false);
    console.log('ON_MOUSE_DOWN ' + isCommandHandled); // here value null
    buttonPressTimer = setTimeout(handleLongPress, 1500, e);
  }.bind(this);

  const handleLongPress = (e) => {
    if (!isCommandHandled) {
      setIsCommandHandled(true);
      console.log('TIMER_IS_EXECUTED' + isCommandHandled); //Here value false or null
      // some other logic for long press event
    }
    clearTimeout(buttonPressTimer);
  };

  const handleButtonRelease = function (e) {
    if (!isCommandHandled) {//isCommandHandled isn't updated here, as a result logic is executed always
       // got regular click, not long press
       // specific logic
      setIsCommandHandled(true);
    }
    clearTimeout(buttonPressTimer);
  };
```

````
<IconButton 
             onMouseDown={(e) => handleButtonPress(e)}
             onMouseUp={(e) => handleButtonRelease(e)}
          >
    ```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use setState with callback and put the set timeout ID to state:

```
 setIsCommandHandled((prevState)=>{ 
        console.log("TIMER_IS_EXECUTED" + isCommandHandled); //Here value false or null
        return true; });
```

Working Example:
  https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-gc0le

Comment: Thanks for spending time. But I think there is some issue. I want to catch events separately. I mean if we got simple click we don't fire logic for long press and vise versa.
```
const handleButtonRelease = function(e) {
    console.log("handleLongPress", isCommandHandled);
```
If I added the previous line I see that in mouse up handler isCommandHandled variable is always false.

Comment: I edited the sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-gc0le
Look at LONG PRESS TIMER_IS_EXECUTED and SINGLE PRESS

Answer (score 0):

This is how I handle a long press:

```
//import Hooks
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Component = () => {
  //pressState
  const [pressed, setPressed] = useState();

  //handleLongPress
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = pressed
      ? setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(pressed, "got pressed!");
        }, 1300)
      : null;
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [pressed]);

  //pressedElement
  return (
    <div
      onMouseDown={(e) => setPressed(e.target)}
      onMouseUp={() => setPressed()}
      style={{ backgroundColor: "lightgreen" }}
    >
      Press me
    </div>
  );
};

export default Component;
```

Tested here: [https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-bose-7vx3qg](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-bose-7vx3qg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)